# the user login view in django is not working properly?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am having a login page after registration page the problem in my login page when I log in with valid credentials it is redirecting to dashboard and when I give invalid credentials also it is redirecting to dashboard with the last valid credentials typed in the login form I am not understanding why it is like that
My views.py

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if there is a post request in the form
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST) #first of all it is a user_form will be posted details present in the user_form
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm(data=request.POST)# after posting the details of the user_form post the details
        if user_form.is_valid() and user_requirement_form.is_valid():
         # if user_form & user_requirement form is valid

         User = user_form.save()#if form is valid save
         User.set_password(request.POST['password'])
         User.save()
         user_requirement = user_requirement_form.save(commit=False)
         # Set user
         user_requirement.user = User
         user_requirement.save()
         user_requirement_form.save_m2m()
         messages.success(request,('Project saved successfully'))
         return render(request,'home1.html')
        else:
          messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the errors above')
    else:  
        user_form = UserForm()
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm()
    return render(request,'register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'requirements_form': user_requirement_form})



def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
                return render(request,'dashboard.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid Credentials')
            return render(request,'dashboard.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')


def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html',);
```

My dashboard.html:

```
<details>
  <summary class="summary ml-4">User Details</summary>
  <p class="p1 ml-4">The contents that are selected by the user</p>
  <p class="p2 ml-4">{{request.user.user_requirement.user}}</p>
</details>

<p class="p3 ml-4 mt-4"><b>Room:<br></b>{{request.user.user_requirement.room}}</p>

 <p class="p4 ml-4"><b>GOAL:</b>
  {% for goal in request.user.user_requirement.goal.all %}
  <br>{{goal}}
  {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</p>
<p class="p5 ml-4"><b>FURNITURE:</b><br>{{request.user.user_requirement.furniture}}</p>
<p class="p4 ml-4"><b>DESIGN:</b>
  {% for design in request.user.user_requirement.design.all %}
  <br>{{design}}
  {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</p>
```

My form.html:

```
 <form action="{% url 'modsy:login' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password2">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
        </form>
```

URLS.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('rooms/', views.project1, name='project1'),
    path('goals/', views.project2, name='project2'),
    path('furniture/', views.project3, name='project3'),
    path('styles/', views.project4, name='project4'),
    path('register/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('user_register/', views.user_register, name='user_register'),
    path('login/', views.login,name='login'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard,name='dashboard')



 ]
```

[image]

Comment: remove this "return render(request,'dashboard.html')" from else part where you are checking user. you are redirecting to dashboard even if user does not exist.

Comment: Also use should use redirect() to redirect user to dashboard after successful login.

Comment: If I remove that The view modsy.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. this error is coming

Comment: because this "return render(request, 'login.html')" is in else part of main condition and function is not returning anything. You don't need "else. Put this line in main function.

Comment: I didnt get you @sandeep

Comment: @sandeep when I give like this return redirect('dashboard') if login success the error is Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
can you please help me

Comment: First if the user doesn't authenticate you should render the login form again, not the dashboard (case incorrect credentials). Second, when the user does authenticate you should **redirect** to the dashboard not render the dashboard. Finally if the user is not active you don't do anything (so you will get a 500 error), you need to decide what to do in that case. Note: You should also protect the `dashboard()` view with `@login_required` that way it's not possible to see it if you're not logged in.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard')) # Edit
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid Credentials')
            # return render(request,'dashboard.html') ## removed 1
    # else: ## removed 2
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

1. You were rendering the dashboard even if user does not exist.
   (Remove 1)
2. `return render(request, 'login.html')` should be part of main function
   because if you are in condition (method == Post) and user not exist,
   there will be no return for the main function.
3. You should **redirect** to the dashboard view, not **render** the dashboard, if login is successful.

Try this. If this raise any issue, please comment. Also you should use redirect() to rdirect user to dashboard.

Comment: yes when I use  return redirect('dashboard') for redirecting to dashboard  Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
getting this error

Comment: this answer will fix the current issue. Don't use redirect here. If you want to use redirect, use correct name of url or show your urls.py. But for now, use the code as it is.

Comment: The OP was not redirecting anywhere, he was __rendering__ the dashboad template. This is really not the same thing (and actually definitly not what should be done)

Comment: I had added urls.py can you say please why redirect is not working

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I know it's not redirecting to anywhere. I Just showed the issue in main code.

Comment: @sandeep no Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
same error coming with edited answer also

Comment: @sssss, can you show screenshot of error because I can see "dashboard" in your url.

Comment: try `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('modsy:dashboard'))`.

Comment: @NalinDobhal that's what `redirect()` will do (except for namespacing the url name of course).

Comment: Yes I had added screenshot

Comment: @sssss url and views both seems correct. can you check dashboard url in browser like "http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/" or whatever url is.

Comment: replace "return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))" with "return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))" or any other url from your urls to check if problem is in dashboard url or urls.py file  or anything else.

Comment: Ya it worked @sandeep return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('modsy:dashboard')) with this